# Building of boost libraries fails

Tags: windows, gcc, boost, build, mingw

I am trying to build boost library 1.58.0 in my Windows with mingw compiler 4.9.2 but it fails.

The bootstrap output gives me following message:

> ### #
>
> #### Using 'mingw' toolset.
>
> ### #
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q
>   bootstrap
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>gcc -DNT -o bootstrap\jam0.exe 
>   command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c
>   frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c
>   jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c
>   pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c
>   timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c
>   class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c
>   modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c
>   modules/order.c
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam
>   --toolset=mingw "--toolset-root= "  clean  ...found 1 target... ...updating 1 target... [DELETE] clean ...updated 1 target...
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam
>   --toolset=mingw "--toolset-root= "   ...found 159 targets... ...updating 2 targets... [COMPILE] bin.ntx86_64\b2.exe [COPY]
>   bin.ntx86_64\bjam.exe ...updated 2 targets...
>
> C:\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\src\engine>exit /b 0

To my eyes it is not clear which is the error.

Thanks in advance.
Nikos

Answer (score 0):

Executing `build.bat gcc` from `\boost_root\tools\build\src\engine` works for me, though I have both a newer version of Boost, and much newer MinGW.

While it may accept `mingw` as an argument, the documentation has used and suggested `gcc` as a toolchain name for a while now, as far as I know.

See [Building Boost Documentation: Identify your toolset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#identify-your-toolset)

Reading your output above again; are you sure there's an error?!

It says that it copied b2.exe and bjam.exe, which are the expected output, no? Check the referenced directory: `[COMPILE] bin.ntx86_64\b2.exe [COPY] bin.ntx86_64\bjam.exe` (\boost_root\tools\build\src\engine\bin.ntx86\) for the files.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the expected result. When I try to run b2 command it is not recognized. I have tried to build several boost versions but all end up with such kind of failures. I've lost my patience and I build the library to another PC and it worked. So I copied  the produced files in my PC. Obviously something is not setup appropriately in my PC for boostraping boost.

Comment: Did you add the folder containing b2 to your system PATH?